# Loop inside angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs

This is a looping question in angularjs. I am little confused about how to get this work. I have a json data:

```
var jungleData= [
   {
    "Area": "Safari Lion County",
    "htdVideo": "",
    "animals": ["lion", "tiger", "Elephant"],
    "animalcolor": ["orange", "yellow", "grey"]
  },
   {
    "Area": "Sea World",
    "htdVideo": "",
    "animals": ["Whale", "Dolphin", "Tarp"],
    "animalcolor": ["blue", "grey", "black"]
  }
];
```

I would like to loop thru' the data in angularjs controller (not using ng-repeat in html) and flush out something like this:

```
Safari Lion County

Lion-black
tiger-yellow
Elephant-grey

Sea World

Whale-blue
Dolphin-grey
Tarp-black
```

How can I implement this loop? may be a simple question for you guys

Comment: please define *"flush out something"*

Comment: Why don't you want to use `ng-repeat`?

Comment: If you could "flush that out" in your server side code, it'd be much nicer.  Here are two examples, one with the data properly formatted from the beginning, and a hacky way (which you're going to have to do if you want to base everything on array indices). [see jsBin](http://jsbin.com/vedimoruva/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @floribon- If I have to get data from multiple controllers and multiple factories based on clicking different links/buttons (created on the fly from data field), I have to use different logic\data fields in different controllers. So, ng-repeat will be hard to implement-I guess. The data provided was a small sample of multiple json documents. Please add to the discussion- if I am wrong. I am a beginner in Angular.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the answer and cleaning up the json code. However, t am thinking of a solution without ng-repeat due to the reason I mentioned to floriban.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a pure javascript question.  Something like:

```
var jungleDataFlush = function(data)
{
  data.forEach(function(place) 
  {
    console.log(place.Area);
    console.log();
    place.animals.forEach(function(animal,index)
    {
      console.log(animal + ' - ' + place.animalcolor[index]);
    });
    console.log();
  });
};
jungleDataFlush(jungleData);
```

Of course you would really want to clean up your model.  Animal should be an object, not array:

```
var animal = { type: 'Lion', color: 'Green' };
```